# Windows UUID Does not match motherboard (digits are shuffled)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, hp-envy, uuid

I have a few laptops with Windows 10 installed and I can use
`(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystemProduct).UUID` in PowerShell
to get each machine's UUID. What's interesting is that the UUID I get from Windows doesn't match what is displayed in the BIOS. All the same digits are there but some are out of order. For example, Windows 10 returns:

`34444335-3632-3036-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX`

but when I am booted into the BIOS of my HP Envy laptop I see:

`35434434-3236-3630-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXX`

where the `X` values represent digits which match exactly between the two. It's interesting, because the UUIDs match perfectly between the BIOS and Windows 10 on a Sony Vaio laptop I have. It's only wrong on the HP.

**Any thoughts as to why?**

Answer (score 0):

See [System Management BIOS (SMBIOS) Reference Specification 3.6.0](https://www.dmtf.org/sites/default/files/standards/documents/DSP0134_3.6.0.pdf), page 38:

> Although RFC4122 recommends network byte order for
> all fields, the PC industry (including the ACPI, UEFI,
> and Microsoft specifications) has consistently used
> little-endian byte encoding for the first three fields:
> time_low, time_mid, time_hi_and_version. The same encoding,
> also known as wire format, should also be used for the
> SMBIOS representation of the UUID.
>
> The UUID {00112233-4455-6677-8899-AABBCCDDEEFF} would thus
> be represented as: 33 22 11 00 55 44 77 66 88 99 AA BB CC DD EE FF.

Apparently, either the BIOS or Windows uses the wrong byte order in your case.

(I know this is an old question, but I thought this answer may still be useful for others stumbling on this via Google, or be scraped and used as part of a curated training set for some AI...).